# trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory Exception :AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'positions'

Tags: ros, ros-control, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote a python script to publish a JointTrajectory message. It results in an Exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'positions'.

The python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rospy
import numpy
from trajectory_msgs.msg import JointTrajectory

rospy.init_node('topic_publisher')

pub= rospy.Publisher('Command',JointTrajectory,queue_size=2)
rate = rospy.Rate(2)

msg=JointTrajectory()
#msg.points=dict()
pos=[1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3]
velo=[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
time=[2.0,0.0]
msg.joint_names=["hip","shoulder","elbow","wrist"]
msg.points=dict([('positions', pos), ('velocities', velo), ('time_from_start', time)])
#msg.points={'position':pos,'velocities':velo,'time_from_start':time}
print (msg)
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    pub.publish(msg)
    rate.sleep()
```

I added a print to show the message.

Result:

```
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs:         0
  frame_id: ''
joint_names: 
  - hip
  - shoulder
  - elbow
  - wrist
points: {'positions': [1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3], 'velocities': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'time_from_start': [2.0, 0.0]}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/KubuntuDaten/myrobot_ws/src/myrobot/topic_publisher.py", line 23, in 
    pub.publish(msg)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 882, in publish
    self.impl.publish(data)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 1066, in publish
    serialize_message(b, self.seq, message)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/msg.py", line 152, in serialize_message
    msg.serialize(b)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/trajectory_msgs/msg/_JointTrajectory.py", line 110, in serialize
    length = len(val1.positions)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'positions'
```

Now I am a bit confused of which type the data element points should be. Is it a list, a dict or a string? I tried several variations of the message format, always with the same result.

ROS noetic runs on Ubuntu focal.

This is my testcoding:

`import rospy
import numpy
from trajectory_msgs.msg import JointTrajectory
from trajectory_msgs.msg import JointTrajectoryPoint

rospy.init_node('topic_publisher')

pub= rospy.Publisher('arm_controller/command',JointTrajectory,queue_size=2)
rate = rospy.Rate(30)

r0=0.0
r1=0.5
r3=0.0
r4=0.0
t=20.0
msg=JointTrajectory()
point=JointTrajectoryPoint()
point.positions=[r0,r1,r3,r4]
point.velocities=[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
point.time_from_start=rospy.Duration(t)
msg.joint_names=["hip","shoulder","elbow","wrist"]
msg.points.append(point)
while not rospy.is_shutdown():

    pub.publish(msg)
    if point.positions[0] >= 2*numpy.pi :
        point.positions[0] = 0.0
    point.positions[0]+=0.7854*2

    rate.sleep()`



---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355108/trajectory_msgs/jointtrajectory-exception-:attributeerror:-'str'-object-has-no-attribute-'positions'/) by [GUENNI](https://answers.ros.org/users/55678/guenni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2020-06-17


Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now I got my robot arm to work. I switched from the python interface to c++. The central aspect for my problem with the jointTrajectory structure was, that I had to resize the arrays for joint_names, points, positions etc. to the desired number of elements.

Here my example code:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory.h"
#include "trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectoryPoint.h"

#define PI 3.141592653589793

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "topic_publisher");

  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise("arm_controller/command", 10);

  ros::Rate loop_rate(0.5);

 trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory msg;
        msg.joint_names.resize(4);
        msg.joint_names[0] = "hip";
        msg.joint_names[1] = "shoulder";
        msg.joint_names[2] = "elbow";
        msg.joint_names[3] = "wrist";
        msg.points.resize(1);
        msg.points[0].positions.resize(4);
        msg.points[0].positions[0] = 1.5;
        msg.points[0].positions[1] = 0.5;
        msg.points[0].positions[2] = 0.6;
        msg.points[0].positions[3] = 0.6;

        msg.points[0].velocities.resize(4);
        msg.points[0].velocities[0] = 0.0;
        msg.points[0].velocities[1] = 0.0;
        msg.points[0].velocities[2] = 0.0;
        msg.points[0].velocities[3] = 0.0;

        msg.points[0].time_from_start=ros::Duration(2);
  while (ros::ok())
  {
          if (msg.points[0].positions[0] >= 2*PI)
                  msg.points[0].positions[0] = 0.0;
          else
                msg.points[0].positions[0] += 0.7;
//      ROS_INFO("%f:%f", msg.points[0].positions[0],msg.points[0].positions[0]);
    chatter_pub.publish(msg);

    ros::spinOnce();

    loop_rate.sleep();
  }


  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [GUENNI](https://answers.ros.org/users/55678/guenni/) with karma: 56 on 2020-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2020-06-25**:
Great! seems a very clear code!
The line:

```
ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<trajectory_msgs::jointtrajectory>("arm_controller/command", 10);
```

i think the message type sould be changed to trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory (if not, i do not know how that's gonna work, but you know, is something minimal!

Personally i prefer to use C++ and this resize. It could seem annoying but actually you are controlling better the code! :)

**Comment by [GUENNI](https://answers.ros.org/users/55678/guenni/) on 2020-06-26**:
Thank you for your good ideas. The misspelled jointtrajectory must be an error on copying the source code. I agree with you concerning coding in C++. It makes it also more clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don' t usually use rospy, but i think you should declare first a JointTrajectoryPoint and then add this as vector element inside JointTrajectory element

maybe something like:

```
point=JointTrajectoryPoint()
point.positions = [1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3]
point.velocities = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
point.time_from_start = [2.0,0.0]
```

then:

```
msg.points.append(point)
```

Hope this helps. I'm not sure if the error is around here or if this is correct, but at least, while nobody answers...

remember to add this import at beggining:

```
from trajectory_msgs.msg import JointTrajectoryPoint
```

---

Originally posted by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) with karma: 187 on 2020-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2020-06-17**:
btw maybe you should check to use numpy also, haha http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/numpy

**Comment by [GUENNI](https://answers.ros.org/users/55678/guenni/) on 2020-06-17**:
This was a good idea. In addition I had to change the entry for time_from_start to `point.time_from_start=rospy.Duration(2)`.
Thank you.

**Comment by [GUENNI](https://answers.ros.org/users/55678/guenni/) on 2020-06-17**:
The solutution from Solrac3589 worked.

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2020-06-18**:
Was something i also wanted to comment (the duration).

In order to not have this mistake again, check the message documentation (for example http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/trajectory_msgs/html/msg/JointTrajectory.html) here you can se clearly the structure

**Comment by [GUENNI](https://answers.ros.org/users/55678/guenni/) on 2020-06-20**:
Another thing, what I do not understand is, I can make a message structure and publish it. But when I try to modify values in the structure, adding  a value to x-position or to time_from_start for example, this is not possible.

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2020-06-20**:
I am not properly understanding what you want. Do you want to change the value of an already sended message? i think its kinda strange.
If you want to send another message for the same channel,, it's not okay to change msg and then publish again?

**Comment by [GUENNI](https://answers.ros.org/users/55678/guenni/) on 2020-06-20**:
My understanding is, that the message structure is a datastructure in my program and I am giving a pointer to the message publisher. Then it must be possible to change a value to create a new message, for example in a loop. Anotheri Idea is to construct a message with several waypoints and read the value from the previous index and add something to it for the next index. I can use the append method to add the point structure to the message, so it must be possible to modify values in the point structure and add it repeatedly to the message. Then publish one message with several waypoints.

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2020-06-20**:
If I am not wrong it's true that the publisher is a pointer, but is a pointer of a copy of the message (that's one of the biggest differences between nodes and Nodelets) so, when you publish a message, I think there is no way to change the value sended.

Checking what you want, yes, i think the better approach is to send a trajectory with several points, but the hard part will be to define the acceleration and velocity of each internal point. However, it also exist the possibility to send several trajectories with one point and they will be executed as a pipeline (i use that in a project!)  the bad part of that is you are gonna see that for each point it will be a acceleration an deceleration. Hope i am understanding well the issue and I cleared a little your mind! if not, just ask, haha :)

**Comment by [GUENNI](https://answers.ros.org/users/55678/guenni/) on 2020-06-20**:
Thank you for the great comment. I am just digging into the materia. If I understand it correct, I have, each time I publish a message, instantiate a new datastructure.

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2020-06-20**:
Actually is not necessary to instantiate a new one. you can resend the same. For example, imagine you wanna send a second trajectory with a different point. you can use msg variable (the one used at the example), just change the values and publish it again. Nevertheless, the original message will not be changed, it will be considered a second message in the same channel

**Comment by [GUENNI](https://answers.ros.org/users/55678/guenni/) on 2020-06-20**:
That's exactly what I tried. But I could not change the value.  The error message is: "positions is not subscriptable". I must also increase the time_from_start. Otherwise I get an error " Trajectory message contains waypoints that are not strictly increasing in time.
I think I must have further tries.

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2020-06-20**:
I think we are kinda misunderstanding. There is somekind of code i can check to se what are you doing?

**Comment by [GUENNI](https://answers.ros.org/users/55678/guenni/) on 2020-06-20**:
I added my code in the question section. Now it seems to run quite well. However I expected, that my robotarm will take full rotations by 360 deg in the hip joint. But it stops to move at about 30 deg. I added the reset of the joint value to 2 pi for limiting the incrementation.

**Comment by [GUENNI](https://answers.ros.org/users/55678/guenni/) on 2020-06-20**:
I see it must be a problem with the timing of the messages. I think I'll get it.

**Comment by [GUENNI](https://answers.ros.org/users/55678/guenni/) on 2020-06-23**:
Now I got my robot arm to work. I switched from the python interface to c++. My example code I post in the question section. The central aspect for my problem with the jointTrajectory structure was, that I had to resize the arrays for joint_names, points, positions etc. to the desired number of elements.